# Start on tick the 1st day of the month (Highcharts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am working on a chart and I have been asked to put the first X axis tick in te 1st day of the month (and no the first monday as default), but I do not find any property related in the api documentation.

I have also been asked to change the line color in the weekends (and special days). I have thought passing an array of days, but I do not see any option to change de color of the line in some points.

Thanks too much to everybody!

Answer (score 0):

In case when you would like to color part of "line" series, you need to have two series, first with days (normal color), second with weekends (colored version).

About starting ticks, you can use min value / pointStart or tickPositioner.

All functions are documented here:

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock